# Button Switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this to work in jquery. I am using this code as an alternative to having to define each button, however this does not work :/

http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/FV4jW/1/

Also, I was wondering if/how I can use more than one statement for each case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a **break** after **each** case in your **switch** statement.  Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FV4jW/9/).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Switch_statement):

> break; is optional; however, it is usually needed, since otherwise code execution will continue to the body of the next case block.
>
> Add a break statement to the end of the last case as a precautionary measure, in case additional cases are added later.

Updated Javascript:

```
 $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
   switch(this.id) {
     case 'buttonone': $("#content").html("Content changed"); break; //notice BREAK
     case 'buttontwo': $("#content").html("Content changed again"); break;
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    switch (this.id) { 
    case 'buttonone':
        $("#content").html("Content changed");
        break;
    case 'buttontwo':
        $("#content").html("Content changed again");
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: `this.id` is faster and more readable than `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, this also clears up my question about using more statements :) I am thankful for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    switch(this.id) {
        case 'buttonone' : 
            $("#content").html("Content changed");
            break;
        case 'buttontwo' : 
            $("#content").html("Content changed again");
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'buttonone' : $("#content").html("Content changed"); break;
        case 'buttontwo' : $("#content").html("Content changed again"); break;
    }
});
```

You forgot the `break` after each case, had an extra `)}` at the end and also you need to use `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`